# Is there a term for rewriting code from an interpreted language to a compiled one

Tags: terminology

I'm currently trying to turn some R code (interpreted language) into C code (a compiled language), and I need to explain what is being done and/or why.

Does anybody know of a term/verb for this sort of practice?

Comment: [Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) or if you want to sound fancy, transpiler.  There is no difference between compiling C (one language) to assembly (another language) and compiling SomeLanguage (one language) to C (another language).  That's what a compiler does.

Comment: TIL transpilers are things.

Comment: They are. They are also called [source to source compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler).  But they are still compilers.

Comment: In my mind, a compiler is something which computers do 'automatically'. Does me doing an manual translation of the code count as compiling R to C code though?

Comment: That is more commonly known as "[porting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting)".

Comment: A *transpiler* is a compiler-like tool that translates one programming language to another. If you are manually rewriting a program in another language, this is called *porting*.

Comment: The more you know I guess, thank you! Would you like to write an answer @MichaelT?

Comment: I am very interested about the "why" too: porting from R to C seems like an adventurous thing to do.

Comment: Algorithm development and statistical analysis in R needs to be turned into something which can sit on and run within a whiteware appliance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because word definitions are not conceptual programming problems as defined in the help center.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are talking about a manual rewrite of the code in another language, then as MichaelT suggested in the comments, "**porting**" would be the most likely term.

While the historical connotation would be that "porting" is something you do to make software written for one hardware platform or operating system run on a different one, it can certainly also apply to rewriting from one language to another.

e.g. I work in the .NET field, and a lot of popular libraries and packages are ports of ones originally written in Java or other languages. For instance, unit-testing framework [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) describes itself as "Initially **ported** from [JUnit](http://junit.org/)" (emphasis mine).

As for specifically rewriting code from an interpreted language to a compiled one - I don't think you'll find any word for that.

---

If, however, you are talking about using a tool which takes in R code and produces C code (thanks @aeongrail for point out that I had overlooked this), then the Wikipedia article on [source-to-source compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) offers "**transpiling**" and "**transcompiling**" as two possible words.

Comment: The transpiling comment is in my opinion a reasonably close answer too. A word specifically for rewriting code from an interpreted language to a compiled one would, at least in my mind, be relatively useful. Someone should get the Oxford dictionary on that

Comment: @aeongrail I realized that when I wrote this, I was thinking the OP had specified that this was a manual rewrite. I now realize that they did not - they just said "turn some R code into C code". If we were talking about using a tool to do the work, [transpiling would definitely be a word for it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler)

Comment: @aeongrail added a paragraph to the answer, thanks!

Comment: Software tools to convert files from one format to another are called _translators_. _Compilers_ and _interpreters_ are both types of translators.